# Switched for Federated Login in App Engine, now users must login every few hours

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, federated-identity

I switched from Google Accounts API to Federated Login today and my users are reporting that they must login every few hours now, where before they could be logged in permanently.

Is there anything I can do to extend the time my users are logged in for when using Federated login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody suggested I increase the Cookie Expiration to 1 or 2 weeks and that this should solve the issue. I will come back and delete this answer if it does not.